# JasperReports: set textfield height to height of other element in band

Tags: jasper-reports, height

I have several textfields on a single row in the same band. The first of them is having a larger font than the rest. However, the size of this font might change for each record. How can I set the height of the other textfields to be dependant of the height of the first one?

Thanks for your help,

Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each field in the row set `Stretch Type` to be `Relative to Tallest Object`.